# input returns true on an empty input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I can't get my head around this issue! 
I have simple jquery validation on button click to validate if the input field is empty.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/fyxP8/3/

I have no idea why the input filed returns with value not empty when it is empty.

Any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 7):

see this demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Tj7Z8/

extra `;` on your if statement

Hope it fits the need `:)`

**code**

```
function checkinputs(ticker, btn) {
    alert(ticker + "[ " + $(btn).parent().find("input").val() + " ]" + $(btn).parent().find("input").val().length);
    var x = false;
    if (ticker == 0) {
        if ($(btn).parent().find("input").val() != '' ) {
            alert($(btn).parent().find("input").attr("name") + "<>" + $(btn).parent().find("input").val());
            x = true;
        }
    }

    return x;
}
var progressTicker = 0;
$("button[class$='nextBtn']").click(function() {
    var returns = checkinputs(progressTicker, this);
    alert(returns);
    if (returns == true) {
        alert('inside');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just had a typo in your script in this line

```
    if ($(btn).parent().find("input").val() != '' ); {
```

The colon is misplaces there...
Compare

http://fiddle.jshell.net/fyxP8/10/

Answer (score 2):

```
if (condition);
{
   operation();
}
```

The first `;` closes the if, so operation will always be executed regardless of the value of condition. On the other hand, this is correct:

```
if (condition)
{
   operation();
}
```

Comment: That's right, but don't feel bad about that, all of us make those mistakes sometimes, especially if we are tired.